# getList() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface

Tags: magento2, api, products

Been trying to figure out what is going on here, but gotten stuck. Anyone got an idea as to what is going on. Using magento 2.2.4

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::getList() must be
>   an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface, string
>   given in
>   C:\wamp64\www\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor.php
>   on line 85
>       ( ! ) TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor::getList() must be
>   an instance of Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface, string
>   given in
>   C:\wamp64\www\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository\Interceptor.php
>   on line 85

[image]

Code I try to execute:

```
set_time_limit(0);
define('TOKEN', 'token code');
define('URL', 'http://localhost:8080/magento2/index.php'); 
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ". TOKEN);
//API URL to get all Magento 2 modules
$requestUrl = (URL . "/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=");
$ch = curl_init($requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the param value:

> $requestUrl = (URL . "/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria=[]");